# Can you use the ideal gas law for flow in pipes?

Tags: ideal-gas

Or is it limited to gas in a container?
This would be in a low temp and pressure, say 70F and 1atm.

The only assumption I can think that might be violated is:

- The gas molecules are assumed to be in random motion, which leads to a uniform distribution of velocities.

Because there is a bulk velocity in the gas in the direction of fluid flow.

Comment: you can probably use it co-moving frame of the gas

Comment: Your question is about fluid-dynamics. If your fluid is an ideal gas, then yes you can use the ideal gas EOS to close the hydrodynamic equations.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal gas law connects the gas pressure with the temperature and particle concentration. This implies that the gas pressure is the same everywhere (no drop of pressure) and in all directions. It's not valid for a gas flow, so you can't directly apply the ideal gas law.